# Package.xml autorefresh VSCode [Salesforce Metadata API]

Tags: visual-studio-code, package, salesforce, apex, sfdc-metadata-api

Is it possible to have VSCode retrieve and update automatically the package.xml file on a daily basis and bring the latest metadata components to it.

Answer (score 1):

Without any extra plugins you can view all metadata in the org using the cloud icon. I don't think it edits the package.xml for you and doesn't react to Shift (select multiple items) but well, it's something.

[image]

Try the VSCode plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator

Works pretty well for me (icons don't match dark mode too well but it does what I'm missing from Eclipse so :)). I'm not affiliated to the extension.

You could also play with https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/